# Slice category - origin of the name

Tags: category-theory, terminology, slice-category

Where does the name "slice category" originate for the category $(\mathscr{C} \downarrow C)$ of objects over $C$?

Comment: A quick search on MathSciNet tells me that the term slice category was used at least around 1980 without explanation in [this review](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=567064).

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994256/whats-a-good-motivating-example-for-the-concept-of-a-slice-category) which provides some motivating examples will help explain the name.

Comment: The name comma category (which is a generalisation of a slice category) comes from the fact that it was used to be denoted with a comma ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category)). A slice category is sometimes denoted as $\mathcal{C} / C$, so perhaps the term slice category comes from the $/$ symbol.